# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'Project_ID_Backend'.'

Tags: c#

I have written this C# application that acts as a database to keep track of projects and notes on the projects. I had it all working fine but then I needed to change the ProjectID column to not be an integer value (the project id's start with letters) so I had to add a new column to be able to accept this.

I kept the old project ID and renamed it "Project_ID_Backend" so my code would still work. (The way I have it written was that if the Project ID was greater than 0, things would happen.

Now whenever I click on the datagridview I am getting an error message. It used to work where when you would click on the datagridview, the contents of that row in the grid would populate the textboxes automatically making it easy to make changes to the records.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SFTool
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("my connection string here");

    public int ProjectIDBackend;
    public int NoteID;

    private void MainForm_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        // load in sql data to the data grid view
        GetProjectsDataset();


        // load notes database into the notesDataGridView
        GetNotesDataset();


        PopulateListBoxes();
       
    }

    private void PopulateListBoxes()
    {
        List<string> ProjectStatusList = new List<string>();
        ProjectStatusList.Add("Working");
        ProjectStatusList.Add("Submitted");
        ProjectStatusList.Add("Reviewed");
        ProjectStatusList.Add("Completed");

        projectStatusListBox.DataSource = ProjectStatusList;


        List<string> ProjectTypeList = new List<string>();
        ProjectTypeList.Add("New build");
        ProjectTypeList.Add("MAC");
        ProjectTypeList.Add("Decom");

        projectTypeListBox.DataSource = ProjectTypeList;
    }

    private void GetNotesDataset()
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfNotes", con);

        DataTable dtNotes = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtNotes.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();

        notesDataGridView.DataSource = dtNotes;

        // Automatically resizes the columns to fit the data grid view
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    }

    private void GetProjectsDataset()
    {
        
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT Project_ID AS 'Project ID', First_Name AS 'First Name', Last_Name AS 'Last Name', Project_Type AS 'Type', Project_Status AS 'Project Status', Last_Updated AS 'Last Updated', Last_Updated_By AS 'Last Updated By', Project_ID_Backend AS 'P.ID Backend'  " +
                                        "FROM sfProjects", con);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dt.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();

        dataGridView.DataSource = dt;

        // Automatically resizes the columns to fit the data grid view
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
    }

    private void insertButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // allow user to insert data into the database, or create new records
        if (IsValid())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sfProjects VALUES (@Project_ID, @FirstName, @LastName, @Project_Type, @Project_Status, @Last_Updated, @Last_Updated_By)", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", projectIDTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstNameTextBox.Text); // maps @FirstName to the firstName textbox
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastNameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Type", projectTypeListBox.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Updated", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Updated_By", System.Environment.MachineName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Status", projectStatusListBox.SelectedItem);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New record has been successfully added to the database", "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
            GetProjectsDataset();

            // reset form controls
            ResetFormControls();
        }
    }

    // data validation. (Make sure name is never empty)
    private bool IsValid()
    {
        if (firstNameTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("First Name is required.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }

        // else return true (it is valid)
        return true; 
    }

    private bool IsNotesValid()
    {
        if (notesProjectIDTextBox.Text == string.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Project ID is required in order to assign a note to a project.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }

        // else return true (it is valid/Project ID was provided)
        return true;
    }


    private void resetButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // resets, or clears, the textboxes 
        ResetFormControls();

        GetProjectsDataset();

        GetNotesDataset();
    }

    private void ResetFormControls()
    {
        ProjectIDBackend = 0; // resets value of projectID after clicking reset

        projectIDTextBox.Clear();
        firstNameTextBox.Clear();
        lastNameTextBox.Clear();
        projectTypeListBox.ClearSelected();
        projectStatusListBox.ClearSelected();
        notesProjectIDTextBox.Clear();
        notesTextBox.Clear();
        searchProjectsTextBox.Clear();

        projectIDTextBox.Focus();
    }

    private void dataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // WHen you click on a row in the data grid, the textboxes will automatically populate with that rows values

        ProjectIDBackend = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[7].Value);

        projectIDTextBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        firstNameTextBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        lastNameTextBox.Text = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        projectTypeListBox.SelectedItem = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        projectStatusListBox.SelectedItem = dataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[4].Value.ToString();


        // Filter the notes grid to only show notes for the row the user clicks 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfNotes WHERE Project_ID_Backend= @Project_ID_Backend", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID_Backend", this.ProjectIDBackend); 

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();



        DataTable dtF = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtF.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();

        notesDataGridView.DataSource = dtF;

        // Automatically resizes the columns to fit the data grid view
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

        

    }

    private void updateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (ProjectIDBackend > 0)
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE sfProjects SET Project_ID= @Project_ID, First_Name= @First_Name, Last_Name= @Last_Name, Project_Type= @Project_Type, Project_Status= @Project_Status, Last_Updated= @Last_Updated, Last_Updated_By= @Last_Updated_By WHERE Project_ID= @Project_ID", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", projectIDTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First_Name", firstNameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Name", lastNameTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Type", projectTypeListBox.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_Status", projectStatusListBox.SelectedItem);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Updated", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last_Updated_By", System.Environment.MachineName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID_Backend", this.ProjectIDBackend);

           


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Record is successfully updated", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
            GetProjectsDataset();

            // reset form controls
            ResetFormControls();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select a record to update", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }
    }

    private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Confirm user wants to delete by asking "Are you sure?"
        var confirmDelete = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this record? This action cannot be undone.",
                                 "Confirm Delete",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, 
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (confirmDelete == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (ProjectIDBackend > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM sfProjects WHERE Project_ID_Backend= @Project_ID_Backend", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID_Backend", this.ProjectIDBackend); // Project_ID equals "this" ProjectID that I clicked on

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Record is successfully deleted from the system", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
                GetProjectsDataset();

                // reset form controls
                ResetFormControls();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a record to delete", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }

        
    }

    private void notesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Addes note into the database
        if (IsNotesValid())
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO sfNotes VALUES (@Project_ID, @Notes, @Note_Created, @Note_Created_By)", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", notesProjectIDTextBox.Text); // maps @Project_ID to the notesProjectID textbox
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", notesTextBox.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note_Created", DateTime.Now);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note_Created_By", System.Environment.MachineName);


            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("New note has been successfully added to the database for Project ID " + this.ProjectIDBackend, "Saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
            GetProjectsDataset();
            GetNotesDataset();

            // reset form controls
            ResetFormControls();
        }

    }

    private void notesDataGridView_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        // WHen you click on a row in the data grid, the textboxes will automatically populate with that rows values
      
         NoteID = Convert.ToInt32(notesDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value);

         notesProjectIDTextBox.Text = notesDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
         notesTextBox.Text = notesDataGridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       
    
    }

    private void removeNote_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Confirm user wants to delete by asking "Are you sure?"
        var confirmDelete = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete this note? This action cannot be undone.",
                                 "Confirm Delete",
                                 MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                                 MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

        if (confirmDelete == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            if (NoteID > 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM sfNotes WHERE Note_ID= @Note_ID", con);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Note_ID", this.NoteID); // @Note_ID equals "this" NoteID that I clicked on

                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show("Note is successfully deleted from the system", "Updated", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                // now update/REFRESH the database so it shows the new record
                GetProjectsDataset();
                GetNotesDataset();

                // reset form controls
                ResetFormControls();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please select a note to delete", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

    private void searchProjectsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfProjects WHERE Project_ID= @Project_ID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", searchProjectsTextBox.Text); // maps @Project_ID to the search projects textbox
        
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();

   

        DataTable dtS = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtS.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();

        dataGridView.DataSource = dtS;

        // Automatically resizes the columns to fit the data grid view
        dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

        // reset form controls
        ResetFormControls();
    }

    private void searchNotesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfNotes WHERE Project_ID= @Project_ID", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID", searchNotesTextBox.Text); // maps @Project_ID to the search projects textbox

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();



        DataTable dtS = new DataTable();

        con.Open();

        SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dtS.Load(sdr);
        con.Close();

        notesDataGridView.DataSource = dtS;

        // Automatically resizes the columns to fit the data grid view
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        notesDataGridView.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;

        // reset form controls
        ResetFormControls();
    }
}
}
```

This is the section that the error is happening:

```
// Filter the notes grid to only show notes for the row the user clicks 
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM sfNotes WHERE Project_ID_Backend= @Project_ID_Backend", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Project_ID_Backend", this.ProjectIDBackend); 

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
```

SOLUTION: The problem was that I didn't "refresh" the database in SSMS after saving it.

Comment: The exception message is telling you that there is no column in the SQL database table with name "Project_ID_Backend". Have you verified the table schema in the DB table itself and committed any changes?

Comment: An SQL Exception like this is telling you what the problem is and I'd go back and double check the basics. At runtime, the database you're connected to doesn't have a column called Project_ID_Backend  in the sfNotes table. * Are you working with multiple databases? * Are you connected to and viewing the right database? * Have you made the column changes on right database? * are you sure the schema that has been created is the same, no typos on column name ?

Comment: @Luke, Wow that was all it was. I did indeed add that column to the database and verified multiple times. The problem was that I didn't "refresh" the database in SSMS after saving it.

Comment: @Kajin happens to the best of folks ;) - also, I don't think it was the refresh that fixed your issue (assuming you're using SSMS). The transaction occurs when you save, refreshing simply updates your view. My guess is that you forgot to save the first time.

Comment: @Luke, well if that's the case then you must be right! I could've sworn I saved it the first time. Thanks for the help regardless! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check the exception documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1

> The exception that is thrown when SQL Server returns a warning or error.

And the message:

> Gets a message that describes the current exception

So the exception indicates that the query was executed on the database and that message is what the *database* returned. This leads me to believe one of two things.

1. Wrong connection string

You have made the change on a database that is different from the one your application connected to. A dev or test instance that you have not updated yet

2. You hand a pending transaction

You have run the script within a transaction that you have not committed.

Open a management studio and connect to the database that your application connects to. Try to execute the query.

Also check the profile you are building/running the application. Maybe it's release and you have transformed the connection string